# How does the user check whether $y < M$ without knowing all shares?

Tags: secret-sharing

**CRT-based Verifiable Secret Sharing Scheme**

In this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/096.pdf), section 4 Verifiable Secret Sharing Scheme, the dealer phase and the combiner phase are as follows:

**Dealer Phase**

To share a secret $d \in Z_{m_0}$ among a group of $n$ users with
verifiable shares, the dealer does the following:

1) The dealing procedure of the Asmuth-Bloom SSS to obtain the shares
$y_i = y \mod m_i$ for each $1 \le i \le n$ where $y = d+ Am_0 < M$.

Note that the $m_i$'s are large primes where $p_i = 2m_i + 1$ is also a prime for $1 \le i \le n$.

2) Let $N$ be an integer whose prime factorization is not known by the users and the dealer.

Compute $E(y) = g^ y mod P N$ .Send $y_ i$ to the $i^{th}$ user
secretly for all $1 \le  i \le n$

3)The $i^{th}$ user checks $g^ { y_{i} }≡ E(y) \mod p_i$

to verify $y_i = y \mod m_i$ . Then he checks the validity of the range proof to verify $y < M$.

**Combiner Phase**

Let $S$ be a coalition gathered to construct the secret.

The share $y_i$ of user can be verified by the other users by the 
verification equation

$$g^ { y_{i}} ≡ E(y) \mod  p_i$$

If all shares are valid then the coalition $S$ can obtain the secret $d$

In this scheme $y$ is private. So, after knowing all shares of $y_i$, users reconstruct the secret.  But how to verify $y_i = y \mod m_i$  user checks the validity of the range proof to verify $y < M$  without knowing all shares of users.

Could you please explain **how user can verify range**

Comment: As there are several schemes described in the linked paper, it would have been nice to write which one you are asking about. I assume it's the one of Fig. 4. In section 4.1 the authors say that they use Cao's non-interactive range-proof scheme as a black box, and refer their readers to the papers [4] by Boudot and [6] by Cao and Liu. Did you try reading these papers?